Change AssignPublicIp setting to ECS service deployed with CodeDeploy deployment controller
I have an ECS Fargate service deployed through an AWS CloudFormation stack with NetworkConfiguration.AwsvpcConfiguration.AssignPublicIp set to ENABLED. I want to change that value to DISABLED.
However, upon deploying the updated stack, it errors and rollbacks with the following message:

Invalid request provided: UpdateService error: Unable to update network parameters on services with a CODE_DEPLOY deployment controller. Use AWS CodeDeploy to trigger a new deployment.

Is there a way to perform this change with a CodeDeploy deployment? If not, what would be the best way to apply it without having to recreate the whole stack (this is production service with high uptime requirements).
